# How to detect more then 2 second the touchscreen was pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Using Google Chrome and Canary.

How do i detect more then 2 second was the touchscreen pressed? (with mouse it works but with real-touch screen its failing, tested on Surface pro 3)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var clickstart;
  var clickstop;

  $(document).bind('contextmenu', function()  {
    console.log('Touch screen, has no right click.');
    return false;
  });

  $(document).mousedown( function() {
    return false; 
  });

  // With USB mouse pointer it works, but with real-touch screen its not working
  $('#vip_anytime').on('mousedown', function(e) {    
      clickstart = e.timeStamp;
  }).on('mouseup', function(e) {
      clickstop = e.timeStamp- clickstart;
      if(clickstop >= 2000) {
        console.log('>>> After 2 second of hold');
      } else { 
        console.log('>>> Before 2 second of hold');
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `touchstart` and `touchend` events.

```
    $('#vip_anytime').on('touchstart', function(e) {    
        clickstart = e.timeStamp;
    }).on('touchend', function(e) {
        clickstop = e.timeStamp- clickstart;
        if(clickstop >= 2000) {
          console.log('>>> After 2 second of hold');
        } else { 
          console.log('>>> Before 2 second of hold');
        }
    });
```